# How to display scatter graph of binary data in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have the following binary dataset:

```
X = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
]
```

I performed Kmeans clustering on this data:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(X)

centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

Now I want to display the resulting clustering on a scatter graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X, X, s=50, cmap='viridis')
plt.scatter(centers, centers, c='black', s=200, alpha=0.5);
plt.show()
```

But no scatter graph is showing up. Does anyone have an idea where I am going wrong? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen `centers` output? Your data set is interpreted as having 5 points in 50-dimensional space. Was that your intention? After clustering you got 4 points in 50-dimensional space. How do you imagine a 50-dimensional scatter plot?

Comment: I followed the steps given and got the scatter plot. However your data consists of only zeros and ones, and you are essentially using the same x and y axes. The two points that show up are the scatter plot, corresponding to location (0,0) and (1,1). Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? Moreover, see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21477401.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that the binary sequences which are similar in nature (patterns of 0s and 1s) be scattered close to each other while distant otherwise.

Comment: In this case, you probably need not a clustering algorithm, but a dimensionality reduction model, like PCA or t-SNE - see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html